# NgRx store values are undefined

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I try to get NgRx running in Angular 16 but my values keep being undefined. However my state is changing as i can see by devtools. I followed the official NgRx documentation but it just doesnt work.

I added a simple number inside my state because my initial thought was that i fill my other lists inside my state wrong.

[state through devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqpC8.png)

app.state.ts:

```
export interface AppState {
  value: number;
  greiferServices: BrokerEntry[];
  roboterServices: BrokerEntry[];
}
```

this is my app.actions.ts:

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { BrokerEntry } from '../../models/service-responses/BrokerResponse';

export const addValue = createAction('[Services] Add Value');
export const addService = createAction(
  '[Services] Add',
  props<{ service: BrokerEntry }>()
);
```

app.reducer.ts where I also added selectors:

```
import { createReducer, createSelector, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as AppActions from '../actions/app.actions';
import { AppState } from '../app.state';
export const initialState: AppState = {
  value: 0,
  greiferServices: [],
  roboterServices: [],
};

export const selectValue = (state: AppState) => state.value;
export const selectGreiferServices = (state: AppState) => state.greiferServices;
export const selectRoboterServices = (state: AppState) => state.roboterServices;

export const selectAllValue = createSelector(
  selectValue,
  (value: number) => value
);
export const selectAllGreiferServices = createSelector(
  selectGreiferServices,
  greiferServices => greiferServices
);

export const selectAllRoboterServices = createSelector(
  selectRoboterServices,
  roboterServices => roboterServices
);

export const myReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(AppActions.addValue, state => ({ ...state, value: state.value + 1 })),
  on(AppActions.addService, (state, { service }) => {
    if (service.class === 'System') {
      console.log('appReducer: Dispatch System');
      console.log(state.value);
      return { ...state, greiferServices: [...state.greiferServices, service] };
    } else if (service.class === 'roboter') {
      return { ...state, roboterServices: [...state.roboterServices, service] };
    }
    console.log('appReducer: Dispatch Nothing');
    return state;
  })
);
```

Inside this service i parse mock data from a json string which then should be filtered by the class property and added in different lists to the state. For testing i created a "valuetest$" Observable which should observe my "value" property of my state so in my thoughts i have to subscribe to this Observable. However the Observable is called even though I havent changed the state yet and the value of my callback keeps being undefined. I also implemented a much more simpler example i a new project but it keeps being undefined.

```
import { IWsMessage, WebsocketService } from './websocket';
import {
  BrokerEntry,
  BrokerResponse,
} from '../core/models/service-responses/BrokerResponse';
import { AppState } from '../core/store/app.state';
import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as AppActions from '../core/store/actions/app.actions';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {
  selectAllValue,
} from '../core/store/reducer/app.reducer';

export class ServiceBrokerService extends WebsocketService {
  valuetest$: Observable<number>;
  constructor(connectionString: string, store: Store<AppState>) {
    super(connectionString);
    this.valuetest$ = store.select(selectAllValue);

    this.status.subscribe((status: boolean) => {
      if (status) {
        console.log('connection established');
      }

      this.valuetest$.subscribe(value => {
        console.log('Value: ' + value);
      });
      if (this.test) {
        this.test.data = this.getMockData();

        this.systemServices$.subscribe((services: BrokerEntry[]) => {
          //console.log('Services: ');
          //console.log(services);
        });

        this.test.data.result.forEach((element: BrokerEntry) => {
          if (element.class === 'System') {
            //this.store.dispatch(AppActions.addService({ service: element }));
            store.dispatch(AppActions.addValue());
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
  public getMockData(): BrokerResponse {
    return JSON.parse(
      '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id":65535, "result": [{"name":"addService","adress":"127.0.0.1","port":"8100","class":"System"},{"name":"deleteService","adress":"127.0.0.1","port":"8100","class":"System"},{"name":"modifyService","adress":"127.0.0.1","port":"8100","class":"System"},{"name":"deleteAllServices","adress":"127.0.0.1","port":"8100","class":"System"},{"name":"getService","adress":"127.0.0.1","port":"8100","class":"System"},{"name":"getServiceList","adress":"127.0.0.1","port":"8100","class":"System"}]}'
    ) as BrokerResponse;
  }
}
```

my app.module where i register the store

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    StoreModule.forRoot({ app: myReducer }),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: !isDevMode() }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I made a much simpler example with only one value existing inside my state but nothing changes at all so I think it it a basic problem which i just dont see.

I expected as soon as i start observing "value" my callback is called.